# Jquery Countdown timer display only hours minutes and seconds calculated from date

Tags: jquery, html, countdown, countdowntimer

I want to show just the hours minutes and seconds calculated from days. I dont want to show days. how can I do this. I am using this below countdown library

http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/

what I have tried so far is this

```
var myCountdownTest = new Countdown({
                                    time:86400 * 60,
                                    width   : 300, 
                                    height  : 70,
                                    rangeHi:"hour",
                                    style:  "flip"
                                    });



</script>
```

It is showing me HOURS MINUTES and SECONDS but according to the date.means If the time remaing is 2 days and 5 hours. It is showing me only 5 hour

Please help me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var end = new Date('02/19/2012 10:1 AM');

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

        return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

Comment: how can I show this in my plugin. I am using countdown flipper?

Comment: document.getElementById('div-to-display')

Comment: Sorry I want to use the above plugin. Because i want to show the timer with flip.. there is no div. I just copy my script code to anywhere in html and it displays the timer